# Cant access disk space on System Storage DS4700

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, storage, file-sharing, storage-spaces

Im running a Windows Server 2012 R2 and I use IBM's System Storage DS4700.
I used to have access to the disks thorugh the File Explorer and recently for some reason im not able to see that disk anymore.

I have tried to see whats wrong with it thorugh the System Storage Manager and nothing looks weird to me so far.

The system storage ds4700 is connected trhough FC to the server.

What are the steps to conecting a disk space so i'll be able to access it and later on share it though the network?

Comment: How are you accessing the DS4700 via Storage Manager?  IP address or FC control LUN(s)?

Comment: Im currently accessing via Storage Manager and its coonected through the FC. How do I check if its set to FC control LUN?